# ionic 2 sending model parameter in function

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

There is a social sharing app. I want share message from the angular model(s.Text). But Places that are thick not pass in code.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much it is working :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From within template, don't use interpolation i.e. `{{...}}` when either passing values to functions or binding property values. Use interpolation to extract value from a property to your `HTML` template. Interpolation is to display or weave some property value to your `HTML` and it replaces the property name within double braces `{{...}}` with string value of the property.

So you can pass values to your functions like `facebookShare(s.Text)` and set attribute values like `[data-share]="s.Text"`.